# Tests without active browser window necessity

Tags: mstest, coded-ui-tests

Is there any possibility to run written CUIT tests without necessity of having active browser window?

Basically, what I would like to have is just to run a bunch of tests on local machine. And I need to wait until all the tests are executed (each test requires browser window to be active during test run). But during this execution I can't use my machine for any other work - otherwise tests fall due to loosing control on the window. So is there any ability to run tests locally and work on the machine without any limitations simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coded UI Test Needs Active Browser while Execution.

To match your necessity you should try running test cases into virtual machine. That will not affect your work in local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [WatiN](http://watin.org/) and run them by "normal" MSTest/NUnit/whatever instead of using CodedUiTests. It does open up a browser window too, but allows you to interact with your desktop nevertheless.

That of course means rewriting your tests but as these tests are much more readable IMHO this might be worth it.